# How to disable webpack minification for classes names

Tags: testing, webpack, jasmine, karma-runner, minify

I use `jasmine`, `karma` and `webpack` to test my module. The webpack preprocesses my tests files before initiating tests.

In my tests I have the `class Name{...}` to be tested. I create new `Name` instance and then, in my tests I `expect(myInstance.constructor.name).toBe("Name")`

```
class Name{}

const myInstance = new Name();

describe("The object",function(){
  it("should be the instance of Name class",function(){
    expect(myInstance.constructor.name).toBe("Name");  // Expected 't' to be 'Name'.
  })
});
```

But it returns failed tests. I figured out that my `Name` class is parsed by webpack to the `t` class in the bundled file and `myInstance.constructor.name` equals `"t"`.

Can I prevent webpack to change the names of classes/constructors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a build setup for development and production separately, whenever in development mode(which you can mention in the webpack config object), don't apply minification plugin(might be there in your webpack config).

Help links:

1. [Bundling Modes](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/)
2. [Minification plugin Webpack v4](https://v4.webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/)
3. [Minification plugin Webpack v5](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/)

You can use 'keep_classnames' option provided by the minification plugin to keep the class names intact.

Comment: `mode: 'production'` helped. This must be some new release of webpack 4 because I haven't knew about that. thanks

Comment: I don't know exactly in which version they introduced it. It's really difficult sometimes to keep updated with change log.

Answer (score 8):

Install Terser Plugin to customize Webpack `optimization` > `minimizer` options running:

```
npm i -D terser-webpack-plugin
```

...or in the case you use yarn:

```
yarn add -D terser-webpack-plugin
```

Then add this optimization option inside `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: ...,
  resolve: ...,
  target: ...,
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
          keep_classnames: true,
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```