# Generating a class in javascript to match existing sass class name

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass, es6-modules

I am using webpack to generate a single bundle.js file containing everything I need in a single file, and the webpack compiles and seems to contain what I expect. I am dynamically generating DOM elements in javascript that I would like to be formatted with existing sass class specifications as follows:

index.scss:

```css
    .classname {
        position: 'absolute';
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        color: blue;
    }
```

index.js:

```js
    import styles from './css/index.scss';

    console.log(styles);

    let aDiv = document.createElement("div");
    aDiv.classList.add("classname");
    aDiv.style.top = "10px";
    document.body.append(aDiv);

    let bDiv = document.createElement("div");
    bDiv.classList.add(styles.classname);
    aDiv.style.top = "30px";
    document.body.append(bDiv);
```

In Firefox's developer tools, from the console, I can see that styles is an object with a property for each of many css rules, one of which is:

```
"classname": "_2mpyBRPOMJ9D3LKNxOIvrs"
```

In Firefox's Inspector tool, aDiv's class is "classname", but no styles are applied from that class. bDiv's class is "undefined", and no styles are applied there either. I cannot figure out how to get the "_2mpyBRPOMJ9D3LKNxOIvrs" class name, which is different each time I compile, assigned as a class. But even when I do this manually from Firefox, the styles are never applied, and neither "classname" or "_2mpyBRPOMJ9D3LKNxOIvrs" exist in Firefox's style editor.

Is it possible to dynamically create an element that inherits styles from scss via its class name? Or is there a nicer cleaner way to do this that I'm missing? I feel I must have failed to grasp a central tenet of webpacking css into js.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the minification plugin changes your class names to new references when your scss gets merged as css into your code. You can disable this behavior by configuring webpack. Thia answer tells you how to do it:

[How to disable webpack minification for classes names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50903065/how-to-disable-webpack-minification-for-classes-names)